# Couldn't find HourLog without an ID rails 4 record not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to display only records created by the logged in user from the database, and don't know how to go about doing that. I get an error when I try to access the database and identify specific data to pull from it.

Hours Controller

```
   class HoursController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user
  def new
    @hour = HourLog.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
    @entry = HourLog.all
  end
  def create
    @hour = HourLog.new(hour_params)
    @hour.User_id = current_user.id if current_user
    @hour.status = 'Pending'
    if @hour.save
      redirect_to '/dashboard'
    end
  end
  private
  def hour_params
    params.require(:hour_log).permit(:assignment, :hours, :supervisor, :date,)
  end
end
```

Hours View (new.html.erb)(field to enter data into database)

```
<% @entry.each do |hour| %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= hour.assignment %></td>
                <td><%= hour.hours %></td>
                <td><%= hour.supervisor %></td>
                <td><%= hour.date %></td>
                <td><%= hour.status %></td>
              </tr>
          <% end.empty? %>
          <%= form_for(@hour, url: hours_path) do |f|%>
              <tr>
                <td id="dashfield"><%=f.text_field :assignment, :placeholder=> "Assignment"%></td>
                <td id="dashfiled"><%=f.text_field :hours, :placeholder => "Hours"%></td>
                <td id="dashfield"><%=f.text_field :supervisor, :placeholder=> "Supervisor/Location"%></td>
                <td id="dashfield"><%=f.date_field :date, :placeholder=> "Date"%></td>
                <%=f.hidden_field :status, :value => "Pending" %>
                <%=f.hidden_field :User_id, :value => current_user.id %>
                <td id="dashbtn"><%=f.submit 'Create' %></td>
              </tr>
          <%end%>
```

Error:

```
Started GET "/dashboard" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-10 17:29:08 -0500
Processing by HoursController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 18ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find HourLog without an ID):
  app/controllers/hours_controller.rb:4:in `new'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please name the "Hours View" file(s) ?  Also your controller does not have the "@entry" definition from the "hours view", could you please add the code bit where this comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this function:

```
def new
   @hour = HourLog.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
   @entry = HourLog.all
end
```

should be changed to:

```
def new
   @hour = current_user.hour_logs.new
   @entry = current_user.hour_logs.all
end
```

Assuming the model `user` is configured with `has_many :hour_logs`.

as in your models, `user` have many `hour_logs` the table `hour_logs` must have a column `user_id` minding the capitalization

to change the column name from `User_id` to `user_id` you need to create a new migration.
in the command prompt navigate to the rails app folder and execute:

```
rails g migration fixcolumn1
```

this will generate a file in `your-app-path/db/migrate` called `some-date_fixcolumn1.rb`
edit this file so the following is present:

```
def change
  rename_column :hour_logs, :User_id, :user_id
end
```

after that go back to the prompt and execute

```
rake db:migrate
```

It should work from there

Comment: I got another error: unknown attribute: user_id ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in HoursController#new

Comment: you need to add the column "user_id" to your "hour_logs" table if you would like to have "hour_logs" belonging to users

Comment: is your view intention to show hour_logs of all users on the @entry part, or only the hour_logs from the logged in user?

Comment: it is my intention to show only the hour_logs of the logged in user

Comment: there is a User_id column, but not a user_id column. I believe it came from the references part of the migrate

Comment: would I need to nest resources?

Comment: you need to change the column name... you can create a migration to fix the column name "rails g migration fixcolumn1". in the script you define a "rename_column :hour_logs, :User_id, :user_id "

Comment: I updated the answer so the @entry would contain only the hour_logs from connected user

Comment: can you clarify how to change the User_id column?

Comment: Couldn't find User without an ID in HoursController#new error. problem with this line of code:  @user_hours = User.find(params[:user_id]).hour_logs

Comment: you probably didn't pass the "user_id" parameter when calling the "new" action... you don't have to. The same line can be represented as @user_hours = current_user.hour_logs.all

Comment: how would i pass that parameter in other cases? thank you!

Comment: YOU SOLVED IT!! THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 2):

Assuming User has_many hour_logs and HourLog belongs_to users ...
**visit "/hours/new?user_id=123"** to fill out your new hour_log form. Upon successful save user will be redirect to "/users/:user_id" page where they will see only records created by current logged in user ... which is what you asked for :) Hope this helps!

```
#config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/hours/new', to: "hours#new"
  post '/hours/create', to: "hours#create"
  get '/users/:user_id', to: "users#index"
end

#controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user_hours = User.find(params[:user_id]).hour_logs
  end
end

#controllers/hours_controller.rb
class HoursController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user

  def new
    @user_hours = User.find(params[:user_id]).hour_logs
  end

  def create
    User.find(params[:user_id]).hour_logs.create!(
      assignment: params[:assignment],
      hours:      params[:hours],
      supervisor: params[:supervisor],
      date:       params[:date],
      status:     params[:status]
    )
    redirect_to "/users/#{params[:user_id]}"
  end
end

#hours view
<% @user_hours.each do |hour| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= hour.assignment %></td>
      <td><%= hour.hours %></td>
      <td><%= hour.supervisor %></td>
      <td><%= hour.date %></td>
      <td><%= hour.status %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
<%= form_for "", url: {controller: 'hours', action: 'create'}, method: "post" do |f|%>
    <tr>
      <td id="dashfield"><%=f.text_field :assignment, :placeholder=> "Assignment"%></td>
      <td id="dashfiled"><%=f.text_field :hours, :placeholder => "Hours"%></td>
      <td id="dashfield"><%=f.text_field :supervisor, :placeholder=> "Supervisor/Location"%></td>
      <td id="dashfield"><%=f.date_field :date, :placeholder=> "Date"%></td>
      <%=f.hidden_field :status, :value => "Pending" %>
      <%=f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => params[:user_id] %>
      <td id="dashbtn"><%=f.submit 'Create' %></td>
    </tr>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Would there be a way to keep the form and the data on one page? so as to have one page instead of a new page and an index page?

Comment: I tried to but it says i don't have enough rep. I need to be at 15. I appreciate everything, and will be sure to upvote as soon as i can

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#index Couldn't find User without an ID error with code: @user_hours = User.find(params[:user_id]).hour_logs

Comment: Visit in ur url "/users/123" given that 123 is a valid user id. Is that what u did?

Comment: I/ll try, but i don't think i have :user_id in my databse. how should i set it up?

Comment: Every record has an id. User.first.id for example. The routes file with get users/:user_id isn't saying look for User.user_id ... It's saying pass the parameter in your url and retrieve it in ur controller.

Comment: but i still get an error. when i visited the users/3 page, it says there isn't a show method written

Comment: 1. That's a different error, 2. The only reason I can think of for you to even get that show method error is because in your routes file you likely did resource routes (don't do that. not saying ever, just not right now) 3. If you are getting an error saying there is no method show perhaps in future you might make one ... def show